# In git how is fetch different than pull and how is merge different than rebase?

Tags: git

I just cant understand this. I been reading a lot on the web and books and something is just not staying in my head. Can someone please give me the dummy version of the following:

- git fetch vs pull
- git merge vs rebase

Comment: I sympathise with the questioner.  The documentation and advice is so heavy and possible workflow permutations so massive that one gets extremely confused.  Ones head just exploded and one doesn't know quite what to ask, it just isn't that obvious.

Comment: Why not choosing pestrella answer as accepted?

Comment: @Arashsoft because he is not seen since 2013

Answer (score 440):

### fetch vs pull

`fetch` will download any changes from the remote* branch, updating your repository data, but leaving your local* branch unchanged.

`pull` will perform a `fetch` and additionally `merge` the changes into your local branch.

**What's the difference?** `pull` updates you local branch with changes from the pulled branch. A `fetch` does not advance your local branch.

### merge vs rebase

Given the following history:

```
          C---D---E local
         /
    A---B---F---G remote
```

`merge` joins two development histories together. It does this by replaying the changes that occurred on your local branch after it diverged on top of the remote branch, and record the result in a new commit. This operation preserves the ancestry of each commit.

The effect of a `merge` will be:

```
          C---D---E local
         /         \
    A---B---F---G---H remote
```

`rebase` will take commits that exist in your local branch and re-apply them on top of the remote branch. This operation re-writes the ancestors of your local commits.

The effect of a `rebase` will be:

```
                  C'--D'--E' local
                 /
    A---B---F---G remote
```

**What's the difference?** A `merge` does not change the ancestry of commits. A `rebase`
rewrites the ancestry of your local commits.

`*` This explanation assumes that the current branch is a local branch, and that the branch specified as the argument to `fetch`, `pull`, `merge`, or `rebase` is a remote branch. This is the usual case. `pull`, for example, will download any changes from the *specified* branch, update your repository and `merge` the changes into the *current* branch.

Comment: This by far is the simplest and best explanation without going into the debate behind each practice. Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely golden answer

Comment: @techsjs2013, five pestrella his points :) Very concise and to the point answer.

Comment: Wish I could "favorite" this answer. Maybe I'll just print it and tape it on my wall.

Comment: I would say the best of best answers I've got in stackoverflow, Thank you

Comment: If fetch only downloads changes from the remote branch and updates the repository data, but leaves the local branch unchanged, then what is the point of fetching if the working directory does not show/reflect the changes? My question originally was that how could I see the changes someone else has done and then decide whether I would like to merge them into my working directory (i.e. experiment with other people's changes to make sure it does not break my work) but I am still confused how to do that? Should I just pul and experiment/explore, and if it was problematic, do a hard reset?

Comment: Hi @Joshua, it's often useful to know when there are new commits on the remote branch without disrupting work on your local branch. If you want to experiment with changes on the remote branch there are many ways to achieve this. Your suggestion is fine. Another way would be to detach `HEAD`, or simply to just create a new branch off the latest commit. It all depends on your specific situation. It's a greater topic of discussion and perhaps out of scope.

Comment: This is similar but more detailed explanation here: https://www.derekgourlay.com/blog/git-when-to-merge-vs-when-to-rebase/

Answer (score 29):

Fetch vs Pull

Git fetch just updates your repo data, but a git pull will basically perform a fetch and then merge the branch pulled

[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

---

Merge vs Rebase

from Atlassian SourceTree Blog, [Merge or Rebase](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/):

> Merging brings two lines of development together while preserving the
>   ancestry of each commit history.
>
> In contrast, rebasing unifies the lines of development by re-writing
>   changes from the source branch so that they appear as children of the
>   destination branch – effectively pretending that those commits were
>   written on top of the destination branch all along.

Also, check out [Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.com/learnGitBranching/), which is a nice game that has just been posted to HackerNews ([link to post](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5236409)) and teaches a lot of branching and merging tricks. I believe it will be very helpful in this matter.

Comment: thanks Felips.. so if I do a fetch from a remote my master branch will not have the updates?  also it sounds like I should do rebase more then merga

Comment: rebase vs merge depends on what is your intention, having in mind that rebase rewrites all commits history. And yes, if you fetch only, the master branch won't be changed, you will have to merge (or pull) for it to apply the remote changes

Comment: `git merge <remote>/<branch>`. for example, if your are the master branch and your remote is named origin, you can do `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: so it sounds like I should always do a 
git checkout master                                                  
git fetch                                        
git diff origin/master
git rebase origin master

Answer (score 11):

*pull vs fetch*:

The way I understand this, is that `git pull` is simply a `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. I.e. you fetch the changes from a remote branch and then merge it into the current branch.

---

*merge vs rebase*:

A merge will do as the command says; merge the differences between current branch and the specified branch (into the current branch). I.e. the command `git merge another_branch` will  the merge `another_branch` into the current branch.

A rebase works a bit differently and is kind of cool. Let's say you perform the command `git rebase another_branch`. Git will first find the latest common version between the current branch and `another_branch`. I.e. the point before the branches diverged. Then git will move this divergent point to the head of the `another_branch`. Finally, all the commits in the current branch since the original divergent point are *replayed* from the new divergent point. This creates a very clean history, with fewer branches and merges.

However, it is not without pitfalls! Since the version history is "rewritten", you should only do this if the commits only exists in your local git repo. That is: *Never* do this if you have pushed the commits to a remote repo.

The explanation on rebasing given in [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) online book is quite good, with easy-to-understand illustrations.

---

*pull with rebasing instead of merge*

I'm actually using rebase quite a lot, but usually it is in combination with pull:

```
git pull --rebase
```

will fetch remote changes and then rebase instead of merge. I.e. it will replay all your local commits from the last time you performed a pull. I find this much cleaner than doing a normal pull with merging, which will create an extra commit with the merges.

Comment: so if I am working in and branch and I want to merge it back into the master before I do a push. I should checkout master, then do get rebase fix?

Comment: I still dont under stand merge vs rebase

Comment: I think the illustrations provided by the answer from pestrella shows the difference quite clearly. Also, check out: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing - which does a pretty decent job of explaining it (same link as the one in the answer, but given again for the lazy ones).

Answer (score 0):

**Merge** - HEAD branch will generate a new commit, preserving the ancestry of each commit history. History can become polluted if merge commits are made by multiple people who work on the same branch in parallel.

**Rebase**  - Re-writes the changes of one branch onto another without creating a new commit. The code history is simplified, linear and readable but it doesn't work with pull requests, because you can't see what minor changes someone made.

I would use `git merge` when dealing with feature-based workflow or if I am not familiar with rebase. But, if I want a more a clean, linear history then `git rebase` is more appropriate. For more details be sure to check out [this merge or rebase article](https://kolosek.com/git-merge-vs-rebase/).