# Syncing fork with upstream: git fetch + git checkout + git merge vs. git checkout + git pull

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fork, git-fetch

The documentation at [Github-Help: Syncing a Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) shows three commands to keep my GitHub fork in sync with the upstream repo.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Can I use the following two commands instead of the above three?

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream/master
```

Are the two sets of commands equivalent, or are there differences between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git how is fetch different than pull and how is merge different than rebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894768/in-git-how-is-fetch-different-than-pull-and-how-is-merge-different-than-rebase)

Comment: `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`, at least in general

Comment: FYI: `git pull upstream/master` is wrong, as the third word (`upstream/master`) must be the name of the *remote*, while `upstream/master` is the name of a *remote-tracking branch*. Git unfortunately uses very similar words that mean very different (albeit related) things: the word *branch* has at least two meanings, the word *remote* by itself has one meaning, and the phrase *remote-tracking branch* has yet another.

Comment: The second set works if you cloned with `git clone -o upstream` or fetched `upstream` at least once. Note that if you cloned, your master branch probably already tracks `upstream/master`, in which case `git pull` is sufficient. Git sets things up for you. However if you created a local copy from scratch (`git init`) and added the remote after (`git remote add upstream <url>`), you need to indicate `upstream/master` unless you setup the tracking yourself (`git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/master`).

Answer (score 1):

These command sets are not equivalent.

```
git pull
```

is split into two commands:

```
git fetch
git merge
```

The problem is, that git fetch requires a remote reference, while git merge requires a tracking reference, this is why the Github help page has:

```
git fetch upstream
```

but it has

```
git merge upstream/master
```

The merge command will take the `upstream/master` branch and merge it into the currently checked out branch (in this case 'master').  But the fetch command doesn't work on a branch, it requires a remote, so when you try:

```
git pull upstream/master
```

Git splits this into:

```
git fetch upstream/master
git merge upstream/master
```

which will fail on the fetch:

> ```
> $ git pull upstream/master
> fatal: 'upstream/master' does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
> ```

Comment: **Note**: `git pull upstream/master` works if you did `git fetch upstream` at least once: `upstream/master` references the local copy of the remote branch, not the copy on the remote server.

Comment: @FabienBouleau That's not correct on my system.  Both a fetch and pull fail using `upstream/master`, even when it's already present.  Fetch needs a remote reference, not a branch reference.  Perhaps if you added the name "upstream/master" as a remote with the same URL/folder as "upstream", or with some other config changes, but not by default, at least when upstream is the secondary remote (i.e. origin is added first).

Comment: My bad, the notation `upstream/master` is wrong in that case. It must be `git pull upstream master` or `git fetch upstream master`. And the first time you download the remote repository it must be `git fetch upstream` (without `master`) or the remote-tracking branch info will not be set (only `FETCH_HEAD`). Use `upstream/master` only to refer to the remote-tracking branch once it exists.