# git fork sync with parent. pull to local, modify and push

Tags: git, rstudio, git-fork

I m a bit confused about the local and git account online. Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602721/syncing-fork-with-upstream-git-fetch-git-checkout-git-merge-vs-git-checkou) has commands like `git fetch upstream`. But how do I use it in the git fork in the browser?

- I have forked a project `project1` into my account (in my git URL). call it `projectforked`.
- Then I created an `R` Project in my local `RStudio` using `projectforked` as my origin. call it `projectforked_R_local`
- Made changes to few files from `projectforked_R_local`.
- In the meantime, `project1` got added with changes

So I am trying to -

- get `project1` changes into `projectforked`.
- Then sync `projectforked_R_local` to `projectforked`.
- and then create a `pull request` to `project1` owner to merge the changes in `projectforked` to `project1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually do this two ways.

- If this is a true online fork, like `project1` is on GitHub and you said Fork and got `projectForked`, there is a button right there on GitHub that lets you bring `projectForked` up to date. So then in `projectforked_R_local` you just pull or whatever.
- Otherwise, you have to use `projectforked_R_local` as the intermediary. You give it another remote, usually termed `upstream`, which points at `project1`. This is in addition to `projectForked` which is probably termed `origin`. Then you fetch from upstream, rebase/merge as desired to a local branch, and push to origin.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the second option to to create branch based on `project1` using `git remote add upstream url` and `git fetch upstream` . Commited my changes in  `projectforked_R_local` and then did `git rebase upstream`. But there were conflicts not resolved. So I created a copy somewhere else. did `git rebase --skip` and modified the files with the changes.. `git commit`,   `git push`. Worked perfect..