# Master branch did not merge properly

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I was updating the master branch on a project. So I checked out my feature branch `feature/branch-A` and merged `master` into it after making sure `master` was up to date with origin. I then checked out master and merged `feature/branch-A` into  `master`.

The issue is the `feature/branch-A` was created from `master commit A`(a past version of master) whereas the `master` branch is now at `commit C` because other work from `featire/branch-B` has been merged to that branch. `commit C` on the `master` branch has files from `commit A` which have been modified and renamed. when I merge `master` into `feature/branch-A` instead of those files overwriting the `commit A` history in the `feature/branch-A` I get the opposite (the files do not reflect the `master` branch at this point in history which is `commit c`). So I now have `feature/branch-A` that *I believe* has been updated with a merge from `master` but in reality the content from `master` has failed to update on the `feature/branch-A`. Now when I checkout `master` and merge `feature/branch-A`, the content of `master` is modified to reflect 'commit A' plus changes from `feature/branch-A` instead of having the current version of master which is `commit C`.

I thought that merging `master` into `feature/branch-A` while having the feature checked out would up date the branch to represent the current version, `commit c`, of the `master`.

My question is why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Maybe something helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894768/in-git-how-is-fetch-different-than-pull-and-how-is-merge-different-than-rebase

Comment: The feature branch was created from a past version of the master branch which is a commit from 24 days ago. Master in its current version has files from 24 days ago that have been renamed and some files that have changed but when I have merged the feature into master the version of those files has reverted to what they were like when the branch was first created. When a merge happens from master to feature, shouldn't the master branch override the changes on the feature?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you mean exactly by "an old version of the master branch has appeared after the merge".
If you want to take a look at your current git status, I recommend using gitk

```
gitk --all & # For Bash shell

gitk --all   # For Windows powershell
```

This will give u  a convenient GUI to check the following things:

- Check if the merge is completed;
- Check if remote branch is also updated;
- Check if you are currently on the right branch and commit;

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Sorry about this but I do not have 50 reputation to add comment

Comment: I have updated the original question to answer the questions I have received for clarification.