# How does a git pull --rebase work and what will show up in remote commit history?

Tags: git, gitlab, version-control, bitbucket, rebase

I am working on a project. Suppose I clone a repository "my_repo" that has `A->B->C` commits. Locally I do a commit `D` on `day 1` but do not push. Someone does a commit `E` on `day 2` and pushes it making the commit history as `A->B->C->E` in the repo. When I do a `git pull --rebase` on day 3 my local commit history becomes `A->B->C->E->D` inspite of the fact that `D` was comitted two days earlier. I was expecting it to be in chronological order `A->B->C->D->E`. If I now push my changes to the remote branch, how will the commit history look like? Can anyone help with this.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14894768/15053790. The remote commit history will also be `A->B->C->E->D`

Comment: What should be done to get it in chronological order?

Comment: Commits can never be changed. If you push, the same commits will be on the remote. Nothing changes wrt. to the commit order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull --rebase` works by first running `git fetch`, then running `git rebase` to get *your local* commits on top of the newly fetched commits (simplified; it involves some reflog magic to find out which local commits need to be rebased).

Initial history:

```
A-B-C        < main, origin/main
```

After local commit:

```
A-B-C        < origin/main
     `-D     < main
```

After fetch:

```
A-B-C--E     < origin/main
     `-D     < main
```

Rebasing will take your *local* commits that are not reachable from upstream and replay them on top of upstream. The only commit not reachable from upstream, but from your local branch is commit `D`. The latest commit in upstream is `E`. In other words: Git will replay the commit range `E..D`; which contains only `D`.

After rebase:

```
A-B-C-E      < origin/main
       `-D'  < main
```

After push:

```
A-B-C-E-D'   < main, origin/main
```

Moving `D` before `E` means that you need to make Git forget about the original `E`, recreate `D` as `D'` on top of `C` and then create a new `E'` on top of `D'`. Then you need to tell everybody else who's working on the project to forget about the original `E` in their local clones and to get the new, rewritten commits instead.